# SwiftUI Initialise variables that will be stored in UserDefaults

Tags: swiftui

I am using AppStorage to save some user settings such as Bools, and I initialise a Bool to true in the class, but am wondering when the app restarts will it reinitialise the variable to that initial value or read the saved value?

```swift
@AppStorage("pullData") var pullData: Bool = true
```

In this example will the class set pullData to what is in AppStorage or to true when the app starts up again?

Comment: It reads saved value. `= true` is a *default*, ie. when there is nothing yet in defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`true` in your example above is the value to fall back on if there is nothing in user defaults. If there is something stored in user defaults for `"pullData"`, it will be used.

If you didn't want to use a fallback value then you'd have to have the property as a `Bool?` instead of a `Bool`:

```
@AppStorage("pullData") var pullData: Bool?
```

But optional booleans are a terrible idea, so don't do that.